# jQuery mobile, on is not working with listview loaded pages, what can I do?

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, jquery-on

I have made a listview with jQuery mobile, and I have an event

```
$("#id").on("click"...
```

the element $("#id") is created after load a new page, this page is loaded when you choose an element of the list (all is automatic, made by the listview funcitions of jquery), but the "on" don't works

I need fire an event after load the new page, what can I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documents, you need to listen to two events `pagecontainerhide` and `pagecontainershow`.

The first event, provides all data related to *next page*. The second event, provides data related to *previous page*.

The odd issue, is that those events no longer accept to be bound to a page id.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerhide", function (e, ui) {
  console.log("Next Page "+ ui.nextPage[0].id);
});

$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function (e, ui) {
  console.log("Previous Page "+ ui.prevPage[0].id);
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/rt7RR/)**